# Android: find the method that uses a specific permission

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I've got the source code for an Android app and its manifest includes a lot of *uses-permission*s, some of which I think it doesn't need. Aside from testing the whole app, is there an easy way to find which classes or methods use a specific permission?

Comment: have you tried using lint?

Answer (score 0):

delete all permission in Manifest, then run App. Then the logcat will show you what permission needed.

Answer (score 0):

As [this](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~dawnsong/papers/2011%20Android%20permissions%20demystified.pdf) paper points out, the API documentation is frequently wrong about which permissions are needed, and many application are 'over-privileged' meaning the manifest declares permissions which are not necessary for the classes and methods used.

Unfortunately, the [Stowaway](http://www.android-permissions.org/) tool described in the paper is currently off-line, and I know of no other tool that is specifically designed to perform the analysis you're looking for. One problem with such a tool is that the *method->required permissions* mapping must re-accomplished based on the Android source code every time a new version is released. The paper is based on Gingerbread and obviously a lot has changed since then. Maybe they are having trouble keeping it relevant.

So at this point, the quickest way to do a one-off check would be to remove all of the permissions and then add them back one-by-one based on the security exceptions you see in the logcat.